# Remove leading string in bash

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a string like `rev00000010` and I only want the last number, 10 in this case.

I have tried this:

```
TEST='rev00000010'
echo "$TEST" | sed '/^[[:alpha:]][0]*/d'
echo "$TEST" | sed '/^rev[0]*/d'
```

both return nothing, although the regex seems to be correct (tried with [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/))

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The commands you passed to `sed` mean: *if a line matches the regex, delete it*. That's not what you want.

```
echo "$TEST" | sed 's/rev0*//'
```

This means: *on each line, remove rev followed by any number of zeroes.*

Also, you don't need `sed` for such a simple thing. Just use bash and its [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion):

```
shopt -s extglob         # Turn on extended globbing.
echo "${TEST##rev*(0)}"  # Remove everything from the beginning up to `rev`
                         # followed by the maximal number of zeroes.
```

Answer (score 7):

POSIXly:

```
test='rev00000010'
number=${test#"${test%%[1-9]*}"}
```

Would remove every thing to the left of the left-most non-zero digit.

Bournely/universally:

```
number=`expr "x$test" : 'xrev0*\(.*\)'`
```

Comment: The first will break with dots, hex, spaces, etc: `test='rev 003A0.1056'` will produce `number="3A0.1056"`. The second will break on any space, the same value will produce: `003A0.1056` from the expr.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the variable TEST just print it with all letter removed

```
printf "%.0f\n" ${TEST//[a-z]/}
```

or

```
printf "%g\n" ${TEST//[a-z]/}
```

Do not use `%d` or `echo`-command becouse numbers with leading `0` is understood as `octal`

Answer (score 2):

A few more options (though I also recommend you use Parameter Expansion as suggested by @choroba):

- Use `sed` or `perl` to replace everything but the last two characters with the last two characters. This effectively deletes everything except the last two.

  ```
  $ sed -r 's/.*(..)/\1/' <<<$TEST
  10
  $ perl -pe 's/.*(..)/\1/' <<<$TEST
  10
  ```
- Set `awk`'s field delimiter to 2 or more 0s and print the last field:

  ```
  $ awk -F"00+" '{print $NF}' <<<$TEST
  10
  ```
- Extract only the last two characters:

  ```
  $ grep -oP '..$' <<<$TEST
  10
  $ perl -lne '/(..)$/; print $1' <<<$TEST
  10
  ```
- Print only the 10th-last bytes:

  ```
  $ cut -b 10- <<<$TEST
  10
  ```

Note that all of the above use `<<<$var` which is a bash construct. To use it in other shells, change to `echo "$TEST" | command`.

Comment: For awk other variant which can avoid some problem `awk -F"[a-z]" '{print +$NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

To get the "last number", select any sequence of digits at the end of the string, and convert it to a decimal number:

With Bash:

```
 [[ "$test" =~  ([1-9][0-9]*)$ ]] && echo "number: $((10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]}))"
```

With grep:

```
echo "$test" | grep -Po "[1-9][0-9]*$"
```